# Can we get all contacts data from xdb through code?

Tags: xdb, contact

We would like to fetch all contacts data from xdb through code in SXA Sitecore 9.1.1.

Could someone assist for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Code below should do the trick. It gets contacts from xDB in batches of 200 and adds them to the list. Then returns the list.

```
public async Task<List<Contact>> GetAllContacts()
{
    var allContacts = new List<Contact>();

    try
    {
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            var query = client.Contacts;

            var enumerator = await query.GetBatchEnumerator(200);

            while (await enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                foreach (var contact in enumerator.Current)
                {
                    allContacts.Add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }

    return allContacts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code suggested by @Marek for you without `async and await`:

```
var allContacts = new List<Contact>();
        using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var enumerator = client.Contacts.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(200);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    foreach (var contact in enumerator.Current)
                    {
                        allContacts.Add(contact);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
```

**For more reference:** You can go with the below articles. It provides you both `Async and Sync` examples.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/search-contacts.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/export-all-contact-data.html